# Selenium script works in debug mode but doesn't run in run mode

Tags: selenium

```java
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\QA INSTALL\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://192.168.103.129:8080/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testIBS651() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/internetbanking/index.form");
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=IBSEnvironmentName | ]]
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("environment_name"))).selectByVisibleText("DEV");
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=IBSEnvironmentName | ]]
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("environment_name"))).selectByVisibleText("QA");
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=IBSEnvironmentName | ]]
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("country_code"))).selectByVisibleText("Australia");
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=IBSEnvironmentName | ]]
driver.findElement(By.id("submit_button")).click();
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=IBSEnvironmentName | ]]
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectbank"))).selectByVisibleText("Queensland Teachers Credit Union");
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=IBSEnvironmentName | ]]

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html//body//section//div//div[2]//form//fieldset[2]//div/input")).click();
}
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html//body//section//div//div[2]//form//fieldset[2]//div/input")).click(); } -------click the button but in debug mode but not in run mode.

Comment: can you help me to understand the question by formatting correctly ?

Comment: Is your page contains multiple listbox/drop down with select tag. If it is not having select tag, then you can not use select class.

Comment: You are attempting to use a direct xpath but passing it as if it were relative by double-slashing all the slashes.  A double slash in XPath has a whole different meaning than a single slash.  You should be using a relative xpath instead, or at least replace all those double slashes with single slashes.  If I could see the HTML code, I could provide you with an alternative relative xpath.

Comment: based on `Unsupported command [selectWindow` looks like driver compatibility issue. Compare your debug and run properties, environment and commands.